# ASP.Net MVC Architecture - Missing a layer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, service-layer

I am using the Entity Framework/Repository-UnitOfWork/Service layer method on this ASP.NET MVC Application and it works great, but it seems a layer might be missing in order to keep the controllers thin.

Lets take for example a user authentication scenario:

1) The `AuthenticationController` takes a `IAuthenticationService` which in turn takes a `IUnitOfWork` and `IRepository<User>` (I am using generic repositories).

2) In the controller I want to make its only concern that the service authenticates the user:

```
if (userService.AuthenticateUser(model.userName, model.password)) {
    FormsAuthentication.SetCookie(...);
    return RedirectToAction(...);
}

return View(model);
```

Some will say this is too much logic in the controller right? So it seems as though we might need a Application Manager if you will:

```
if (appManager.AuthenticateUser(model.userName, model.password)) {
    // Here the app manager calls the service???
    return RedirectToAction(...);
}
```

I am trying to keep my domain services agnostic of the consuming application so I can use them on MVC, WinForms, Console, WPF, WCF, etc.

My service layers only return domain objects, I need a place to transform them into View Models, but I want to keep that out of the controllers.

Any input on this would be great!!

Comment: This might be a better fit for programmers.stackexchange.com, if you're just looking for "best practice" advice. You're definitely heading in the right direction, though.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, one would use something like AutoMapper to map your domain objects to ViewModels.  Then you only have a Map call that wraps your service layer.  There is little reason to introduce an entirely new layer just for object mapping.

Comment: I agree with using AutoMapper, I already am, but in this example setting the `FormsAuthentication` cookie is not the responsibility of the controller, or is it? Also what about a more complex situation where you are building up an aggregate model?

Comment: @SamStriano - You have to realize that the presentation layer is responsible for setting cookies and dealing with front-end authentication.  Setting the cookie is part of the UI layer, not part of lower levels.